# Is it possible to have a app look for "certain features" in a photo

Tags: ios, camera

I want to make a app that allows you to take a picture of a music note that you don't know and the app will analyze the photo to see what the note is. I am new to coding so any help will be great. The app will be similar to the app snap n play but instead of playing the notes it tells you what note it is.

This is my code so far.

(ViewController.m)

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender {

    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    [imageView setImage:image];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
#pragma mark iAd Delagate Methods

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

    [banner setAlpha:1];

    [UIView commitAnimations];


}

@end
```

(VeiwController.h)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> {

     IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

    UIImagePickerController *picker;
    UIImage *image;
}

- (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender;



@end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible. It requires image recognition. However, that's not something that can be answered in a Stack Overflow post.

Try searching online for image recognition algorithms.